# Is pickle not compatible with twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, pickle

I have made 2 application: 
The client extract data from a sql server (10k lines), and send every line pickled to a "collector" server via socket.
The server uses twisted (this is mandatory) and receive every line, unpikle it and store the data in another sql server.

Everytime i start sending data from client to server, in the first 200 line (everytime a different line) **the server** throws an exception:
SOMETIMES it something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collector2.py", line 81, in dataReceived
    self.count,account  = pickle.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1374, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1138, in load_pop
    del self.stack[-1]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

But it's NOT every time the same. Printing my exception i red: 
Exception: pop from empty list
Exception: list index out of range
Exception: "'"
Exception: list assignment index out of range

Another strange errors is:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    **import**(module)
exceptions.ImportError: No module named ond'

```
for i in listaSAI:
    crm={}
    try:
        crm['uid']=i[0]
    except:
        crm['uid']=None
    try:
        crm['type_cond']=i[01]
    except:
        crm['type_cond']=None
    try:
        crm['population_id']=i[2]
    except:
        crm['population_id']=None
    try:
        crm['product_id']=i[3]
    except:
        crm['product_id']=None
    try:
        crm['a_id']=i[4]
    except:
        crm['a_id']=None
    try:
        crm['status']=i[5]
    except:
        crm['status']=None
    #time.sleep(0.001)
    serialized = pickle.dumps((count,crm))
    #print "sent num", count, crm
    s.sendall(serialized)
    count += 1
```

And my server:

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    try:
        self.count,account  = pickle.loads(data)        
    except Exception as e:
        print "Eccezione:", e
        print self.count+1
        print "DISAGIO", data
        print traceback.print_exc()
```

Printing the data in my client tells me that everything it's ok.
*If i try to slow down the process of sending using time.sleep(0.01) in my client, EVERYTHING IS FINE, and no exception are raised.*

What can i do to debug my code?

p.s. 
I suspect that exceptions.ImportError: No module named ond' refers to "type_cond" key in crm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no problem when adding a delay between writes, it is clear the problem is not related to pickle, but to the transport of the data.

One option is that the client keeps writing data to the socket faster than the server can process it, resulting in buffer overflow and packet loss.

Or, do you have more than one thread writing to the socket potentially at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Your protocol has no framing, and you're trying to use a SOCK_STREAM (TCP connection) as if it were datagram-oriented (ie, as a SOCK_DGRAM, like UDP).

So you send some bytes that make up a complete pickled dataset, but the server has no idea where a particular pickle dataset begins or ends.  Instead, the receiving code tries to unpickle whatever random chunk of bytes happens to be delivered to it.

As you've discovered, this works sometimes.  However, there is no guarantee that the bytes you pass to `sock.sendall` will be delivered as a single group to `dataReceived`.  You have to add framing so the receiver can discover message boundaries.  There are several approaches to this.  One approach is to add a length prefix.  Then the receiver knows how many bytes to wait for and can unpickle them when it has received the correct number.

Of course, you should never ever unpickle data received over the network.  See the big red box on http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?  It's there because if you write a server like the one you're showing here, then you've written a server with a remote arbitrary code vulnerability in it big enough to drive a semi through.

Since your data seems fairly simple and structured, I suggest taking a look at [AMP](http://amp-protocol.net/) instead.